# django - Passing varying values through URL

Tags: django, rest, api

I'm new to django and I have to develop a REST API with it. I have datas on mysql db and I want to update one of them on demand. I use PyMySQL and each data has 5 fields (petId, name, species, gender, birthday). For example, urls can be

> .../api/pets/3/update?name=fluffy,age=4

or

> .../api/pets/3/update?age=5

or

> .../api/pets/3/update?age=2,gender=f,name=fluffy

In each case this should update the pet with id of 3 with given parameters. As you can see parameters, their positions and their number can vary.

In my **views.py** I have this method

```
def update_a_pet(requested_pet_id, **data):
   pet = get_a_pet(requested_pet_id)
   pet_id = data.get('petId', pet[petId])
   pet_name = data.get('name', pet[name])
   pet_species = data.get('species', pet[species])
   pet_gender = data.get('gender', pet[gender])
   pet_birthday = data.get('birthday', pet[birthday])
try:
    with create_connection().cursor() as cursor:
        sql = "UPDATE `%s` SET `%s` = `%d`, `%s` = `%s`, `%s` = `%s`, `%s` = `%s`, `%s` = `%s` WHERE `%s` = `%d`"
        cursor.execute(sql, (table_name, petId, pet_id, name, pet_name, species, pet_species, gender, pet_gender,
                             birthday, pet_birthday, petId, requested_pet_id))
        create_connection().commit()
```

I planned to get the id with requested_pet_id variable and all other parameters as **data.

In **urls.py** I have the following line for this task. But I can't figure it out how to pass varying number and type of parameters.

```
url('api/pets/(?P<requested_pet_id>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.update_a_pet),
```

This is what I can come up with so far. If a better approach is possible, I would appriciate suggestions as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've started out is using 'querystrings', not url parameters. REST is for stable urls; the query_strings you are generating are dynamic and a better fit. To get values from a querystring, use [request.GET.getlist()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) for example.  But...

The more conventional Django way would be to use a html form and POST the data back. POST guarantees everything POSTed will reach the server, whereas GET does not, so if you're putting values into your database, you really ought to use POST.  In Django, the data is in request.POST['fieldname'].  View functions expect to receive the 'request' object along with any parameters captured in the URL.

Django's ORM in models.py will let you do just about any sql in Python - in this case you'd have defined pets in models.py with models.CharField and models.DateField types. Then to update a pet:

```
 pet = Pets.objects.get(pk=petpk)  # identify an existing row to update by pk in URL or POST
 pet.gender = request.POST['gender']  
 pet.birthday = request.POST['birthday']
 pet.save()  # generates the SQL and writes it back in a single database action.
```

Django also has a 'forms' module that provides shortcuts / alternatives to manually defining forms in html and getting the fields named correctly. Make a [PetForm(ModelForm)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) and this whole project becomes simpler.